# Are some bigquery public datasets no longer available?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-public-datasets

When using the BigQuery GUI interface, I'm no longer able to browse the `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow` dataset.  It doesn't show up in the Public Datasets dropdown, where I was previously able to view the schema.  On the other hand, I am able to query the table.

Have some public datasets been removed from the GUI?

Comment: @static_rtti -- unclear why this isn't part of browsable public dataset, but I describe how to work around this in an additional answer. I'd suggest following up on BigQuery's public issue tracker for an official response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original issue was due to a bug that caused Pinned Projects to be hidden. It has since been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding static_rtti's request to use the pushshift reddit dataset:

I see two ways to accomplish this:

(1) Using the original UI:

- From the Cloud Console, click "Go to classic UI".
- Click the little arrow next to your project name on the upper left.
- "Switch to Project" > "Display Project"
- Enter "pushshift" (Display Project in Navigation Panel) and submit.
- You should now see a new pushshift project w/ the reddit dataset in your navigation panel.

(2) Using the new UI:

I don't see an obvious way to add a project if you aren't a member, but you *can* use the same trick that the public dataset browser employs. Replace YOURPROJECT with your project name in the URL below and navigate. This will pin the specified dataset for later access.

https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=pushshift&d=rt_reddit&page=dataset&project=YOURPROJECT&folder&organizationId

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for. Unfortunately I didn't log in in time for the bounty. Very sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Use this URL in your browser:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/partners/bigquery-public-data
```

Then you can click on the "view all" button and look for the the ones you need.

This is the link to the [bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/stack-exchange/stack-overflow?q=BigQuery%20Public%20Data%20stac), click on the view dataset to use it in the WebUI.

You can review this document on [accessing the public dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/#public-ui).